# Sf2 RedirectResponse not working

Tags: php, symfony, http, psr-7, symfony-http-foundation

I am using the [HttpFoundation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/index.html) in my project without using the full Symfony2 framework. I try to make a [RedirectResponse](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html) if some credentials are true and redirect the user ([like stated in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#redirecting-the-user)), but the `return` statement is not working.

I have:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$logged = 1;

if ($logged == 1) {
    $response = new RedirectResponse('http://google.com/');

    return $response;
} else {
    die("not logged");
}
```

Nothing happens when i execute this. But if I do this instead, I am successfully redirected to Google:

```
if ($logged == 1) {
    $response = new RedirectResponse('http://google.com/');

    echo $response;
}
```

Why does this work with `echo` but not with `return`? I don't want to use `echo` in my class libraries.

Any solutions?

Comment: return only make sense if it is a called function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try: `$response->send();` instead `echo $response;`.